# How to put 4 sets of two charts side by side on HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie in HTML.
I'm currently trying to put 4 sets of two graphs side by side on a webpage.
So each set would have a graph above and below.
My code is as the following:

```
<template>
<div class = "container">
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-12">
    <div class ="row">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div ref="prpsch1" id="prpsch1" class="height-300">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    <div class ="row">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div ref = "prpdch1" id="prpdch1" class="height-300">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>>
        </div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-12">
    <div class ="row">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div ref="prpsch2" id="prpsch2" class="height-300">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    <div class ="row">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div ref = "prpdch2" id="prpdch2" class="height-300">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>>
        </div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-12">
    <div class ="row">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div ref="prpsch3" id="prpsch3" class="height-300">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    <div class ="row">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div ref = "prpdch3" id="prpdch3" class="height-300">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>>
        </div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-12">
    <div class ="row">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div ref="prpsch4" id="prpsch4" class="height-300">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    <div class ="row">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div ref = "prpdch4" id="prpdch4" class="height-300">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>>
        </div>
</div>
</template>
```

However, webpage just every charts from top to bottom. And those charts are not even whole.

[image]

I want to put the 8 charts in 2 rows and 4 columns in the blank portion of the page.

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please mention dependency for your styles or add the styles you have

Comment: Hey @AmilaSenadheera I'm confused with what you are referring to as dependency here. The code is on vue.js file if that's closed to what you are asking. You wouldn't need dependency to understand my code except for prpsch# and prpdch# which just refer to graphs.

Comment: From where did your style classes come from did you write them or are they from a styles package like bootstrap?

Comment: Please make your code into a working snippet (so you will have to include any libraries you are using). And add any further relevant tags such as vuejs

Comment: Your HTML Code is wrong like class `container` child Class `row` then after `col-*` classes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<template>
    <div class = "container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                    <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div ref="prpsch1" id="prpsch1" class="height-300">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        <div class ="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                    <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div ref = "prpdch1" id="prpdch1" class="height-300">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>>
            </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                    <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div ref="prpsch2" id="prpsch2" class="height-300">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        <div class ="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                    <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div ref = "prpdch2" id="prpdch2" class="height-300">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>>
            </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                    <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div ref="prpsch3" id="prpsch3" class="height-300">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        <div class ="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                    <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div ref = "prpdch3" id="prpdch3" class="height-300">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>>
            </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                    <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div ref="prpsch4" id="prpsch4" class="height-300">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        <div class ="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Graph</h4>
                    <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>                
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div ref = "prpdch4" id="prpdch4" class="height-300">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>>
            </div>
    </div>
    </template>
```

Try this it will definatly help..

Answer (score 0):

**Using Flexbox:**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
}

.graph {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #ccc5, #ccc, #ccc5);
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="graph">Graph 1</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 2</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 3</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 4</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 5</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 6</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 7</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 8</div>
</div>
```

You define graphs' size in `flex-basis`. If you use gap (like my example, you need to substract it from it).

**Using Grid:**
(More useful if you know beforehand the structure of your content)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 500px));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.graph {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #ccc5, #ccc, #ccc5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="graph">Graph 1</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 2</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 3</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 4</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 5</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 6</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 7</div>
  <div class="graph">Graph 8</div>
</div>
```

The magic happens with `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 500px));`. This makes your graphs responsive. It will give them 500px when the graph elements are displayed in a big screen. When you view them in a small screen and elements are going smaller, they will start autofilling below each other.

Comment: Hey @George Thanks for your sharing.
I've just applied flexbox on my code, and all the graphs have become a small rectangle.
I need to resize them somehow.. It's too bad that I can't understand much of your code ;)